# Get desired columns from a select statement in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get brands, each brand contains a list of products and each product contains a brand. It's a one to many relationship

this it the Brand model

```cs
public partial class Brand
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

this is the Product model

```cs
public partial class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; } = null!;
    public short ModelYear { get; set; }
    public decimal ListPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; } = new List<OrderItem>();
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; } = new List<Stock>();
}
```

here is the code in the service that I use to get the brands

```cs
public Brand getBrandById(int id)
{
    var brand = _context.Brands
        .Where(b => b.BrandId == id)
        .Include(b => b.Products.Select(p => new
        {
            p.ProductId,
            p.BrandId,
            p.CategoryId,
            p.ProductName,
            p.ModelYear,
            p.ListPrice,
            p.Category,
            p.OrderItems,
            p.Stocks
        })).FirstOrDefault();
    return brand;
}
```

and this is the controller code:

```cs
[HttpGet("{brandId}")]
public IActionResult getBrandById(int brandId) 
{
    if (!_brandService.isBrandExists(brandId))
        return NotFound();

    var brand = _mapper.Map<BrandDto>(_brandService.getBrandById(brandId));
    return Ok(brand);
}
```

I DON'T want to get the Brand back in my select statement because it's gonna end up in the cycles problem so I want to select certain items but I get this error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'b.Products.AsQueryable().Select(p => new <>f__AnonymousType2`9(ProductId = p.ProductId, BrandId = p.BrandId, CategoryId = p.CategoryId, ProductName = p.ProductName, ModelYear = p.ModelYear, ListPrice = p.ListPrice, Category = p.Category, OrderItems = p.OrderItems, Stocks = p.Stocks))' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations.

I'm new to learning Entity Framework so I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: You've put your Select() inside your Include(). Don't do that.

Comment: But you first call an exists method, then query the record? Why don't you do both at once, leveraging the existence of `null`?

Comment: @CodeCaster what should I do?

Comment: First Include(), then Select()...

Comment: @CodeCaster can you give me more instructions?

Comment: Why not just `.Include(b => b.Products)`?

Comment: `.Include(b => b.Products).Select(...)` and I'm not even sure you still need the include as EF can infer that from what you select.

Comment: You can't use `Select` in an `Include` statement. What you ask here is a notorious problem that's been asked many times. The answer is always: use DTOs or configure the JSON serializer to ignore reference loops.